# Qt Qcheckbox - how to style the tick sign

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt-designer, pyside2, qcheckbox

My setup is Raspberry Pi, Python 3.9.2, Pyside2, Qt Designer. The original (without style) QcheckBox size is too small for my design, So I increased its size with width= and height= (seen here [Increase check box size not its text using QCheckbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302428/increase-check-box-size-not-its-text-using-qcheckbox) ) on Qt Designer.

The problem is that the tick sign remained the same (small), now shown in a corner of the big QcheckBox. So, two questions:

- How to increase the size of the tick sign?
- How to change the color of the tick sign (and not the text)?

I made what is suggested here [Increase check box size not its text using QCheckbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302428/increase-check-box-size-not-its-text-using-qcheckbox) and here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pyqt5-changing-size-of-indicator-in-check-box/ but none of them talks about the tick size.

Answer (score 0):

What about using

```
checkbox.setStyleSheet("QCheckBox::indicator {"
    "width: 20px;"
    "height: 20px;"
    "color: blue;"
"}");
```

Comment: Doing this makes the tick sign either disappear or be small (its standard size)