# Why is QCheckBox checkmark so small?

Tags: c++, qt, qcheckbox, qt4.7

I am using Qt version 4.7.4 to build a Windows app.

The checkmark in a `QCheckBox` is very small and is left-top aligned in the corner.  Here is a snippet of a `QCheckBox` in my app.

[image]

And, the problem is not just with my app.  When I use the Qt Designer that comes with this version of Qt, all the checkboxes there have the same problem.  Here is a snippet of a few checkboxes in Qt Designer.

[image]

I have tried changing the stylesheet for `QCheckBox` without success.  I can change some things via the stylesheet, such as the background color.  But when I attempt to change the images used for the indicator part of the `QCheckBox`, nothing appears.

I have been following the examples from:

- [Increase check box size not its text using QCheckbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302428/increase-check-box-size-not-its-text-using-qcheckbox)

Here are the style rules I am testing.

```
// MainWindow constructor.  MainWindow derives from QMainWindow.
MainWindow::MainWindow( QWidget * pParent, Qt::WFlags flags )
  : QMainWindow( pParent, flags )
{
  ...

  QStringList styles;

  // Force checkboxes to have checkmarks that are easier to see.
  // As a sanity check, changing the background color works.
  styles << "QCheckBox { background-color: rgb( 0, 255, 0 ); }";

  // This does not work.  The checkbox border still renders, but nothing inside the border appears.
  styles << "QCheckBox::indicator { width: 32px; height: 32px; }";
  styles << "QCheckBox::indicator:checked { image: url(:/resources/big_check_32x32.png); }";
  styles << "QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked { image: url(:/resources/big_uncheck_32x32.png); }";

  setStyleSheet( styles.join( " " ) );
}
```

The paths I am using to reference the app's embedded image resources could be wrong.  I have never tried it this way before.  I previously always referenced an embedded image resource via its alias, which works for a `QIcon`.

Is there a better way to fix the very small checkmark in a `QCheckBox` ?

Comment: I would guess you're using a high-dpi display with an ancient Qt version which can not handle it.